# Cannot make https request to my Application Load Balancer - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, elastic-load-balancer

I have and Application Load Balancer (AWS) that has 2 EC2 as targets.  I am also using Route 53 to route my domain name to my load balancer.  So all http requests to my domain name works, but my https request fails.  I do not understand why.  I have done the following:

1. I created a domain name in route53 and have been issued with a SSL/TLS certificate through AWS Certificate manager.
2. For my load  balancer I set up  listener for https:443 and attached the above certificate with it.
3. The security group for my ec2 instances allow http and https requests (although I believe the load balancer ec2 target will communicate using http)

I am totally out of ideas.  I have read the aWS documentation, done what they have instructed and I am not able to make https request.  Please can someone advise?

Result of https  request:

"(red triangle)Not secure https(crossed out)" - this appears in the browser. but it connects anyway.

Comment: What does "fails" mean in this context?  Can't connect?  Bad certificate?

Comment: please se update

Comment: Can you share a url or domain name?

Comment: You are accessing it by entering your custom domain name in your browser, correct? Not by the load balancer's DNS name.

Comment: correct i am using my custom domain. please see above reply to @stdunbar

Comment: @stdunbar domain name: lifescienceecosystem.eu

Comment: So the certificate is for `*.lifescienceecosystem.eu` or `www.lifescienceecosystem.eu` but `www.lifescienceecosystem.eu` doesn't exist in DNS.  You'll need to add a `www` entry to DNS (either CNAME or A record).

Comment: @stdunbar your statement is correct concerning my certificate.

Comment: @stdunbar i have done what you have suggested.  but i don't see any difference it has made

Comment: @johnDoe The existing certificate is for "www.lifescienceecosystem.eu, *.lifescienceecosystem.eu". ACM certificates with wildcard does not protect the apex domain. Can you request a new certificate with "lifescienceecosystem.eu, *.lifescienceecosystem.eu" ?

Comment: @stdunbar adding www. in the DNS made the https request work for www.lifescienceecosystem.eu. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to access via `lifescienceecosystem.eu`, without `www` or another sub-domain then you’ll get this error. You’ll need to reissue your cert for `lifescienceecosystem.eu` and `*.lifescienceecosystem.eu` (or `www.lifescienceecosystem.eu` if you only want `www`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify the following points

1. Have you configured your certificate in the load balancer (ELB)?
2. How you have configured your ELB to route HTTPS requests? 443 to port 80 of your EC2 OR 443 to 443 of your EC2?